# Пронумеровать ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

Добрый день, подскажите, можно ли как-то пронумеровать ListView прямо в Xaml коде? Без добавления нового свойства в модель и прочих манипуляций в кодбихайнде?

```
<ListView x:Name="groupSostav" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndexInListBox}" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsForListBox}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItemInListBox}">
  <ListView.View>
     <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ??? }"/>
        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Target}"/>
     </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

В столбец где {Binding ??? }

Answer (score 1):

[image: демонстрация работы нумерации в ListView]

Нам понадобится класс-конвертер

```
public class ItemPositionToIndexConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ListViewItem lvItem = value as ListViewItem;
        int index = 0;

        if (lvItem != null)
        {
            ListView listView = ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(lvItem) as ListView;
            //нумерацию будем вести с единицы
            index = listView.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(lvItem) + 1;
        }

        return index;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

С учетом того, что этот класс лежит в корне проекта

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:ItemPositionToIndexConverter x:Key="PositionConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

Тогда для `ListView` должно быть так (обратите внимание на раздел `<ListView.Resources>` и на `CellTemplate`)

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Entries}"
        x:Name="listView" Height="193" Canvas.Left="29" Canvas.Top="30" Width="125">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ColumnDataTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListViewItem},
                Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=PositionConverter}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="н/п" CellTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ColumnDataTemplate}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Имя" Width="70"
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding}" />
        </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```